# Edit object with a bootstrap modal form (Ruby On Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am doing a modal form for Groups using AJAX, the idea is that I click the edit button in the table to edit that specific object. When I click the edit button it doesn't show the modal form

***groups.html.erb***

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" >
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Phone</th>
         <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <% @groups.each do |g| %>
           <tr class="gradeC">
               <td><%= g.name%></td>
               <td><%= g.phone%></td>
               <td>
                  <div class="btn-group">
                     <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_group_path(g),  {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#edit-group', class: 'btn-white'}  %>
                  </div>
               </td>
           </tr>

         </tbody>
     <% end %>
</table>

    <div id="edit-group" class="modal hide fade" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <%= render partial: 'form' %>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

***_form.html.erb***

```
    <div id="edit">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12"><h3 class="m-t-none m-b">Edit group</h3>
    </div>
    </div>
    <%= form_for @group, url: groups_path, remote: true do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label>Name</label> 
        <%= f.text_field :name, class:"form-control"%> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
    <label>Phone</label> 
        <%= f.text_field :phone, class:"form-control"%> 
    </div>
    </div>

    <%= f.submit "Submit", id:"submit", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg float-right'%>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

***_edit.js.erb***

```
$('.modal-body').html("<%= escape_javascript( render partial: 'form', locals: {group: @group} ) %>")

$('#edit-group').modal()
```

***_update.js.erb***

```
$('#edit-group').modal('toggle');
$('#group_<%= @group.id %>').replaceWith('<%= j render (@group) %>')
```

***groups_controller.***

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
    def groups 
        @group = Group.new
        @group = Group.all
    end

    def create
        @group = Group.new(group_params)
        if @group.save
          flash[:success] = "Group successfully added"
          redirect_to :groups => 'post', :action => 'groups'
        else
          flash[:error] = "Something went wrong"
          render 'group'
        end
    end

    def edit
      @group = Group.find(params[:id])
      format.js
    end

    def update
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js
        if @group.update(group_params)
          redirect_to :groups => 'post', :action => 'groups'
        end
      end
    end

    private
    def group_params
        params.require(:group).permit(:name, :phone)
    end

end
```

I tried to do console.logs in the javascript files to make sure they are at least trying to execute but I get nothing in the console, guess they aren't executing for some reason, they are inside my views folder

Comment: What if you remove the class `hide` from the modal?

Answer (score 0):

In your _edit.js.erb modify the last line to be:

```
$('#edit-group').modal('show');
```

Also, What is the response you are getting from clicking the edit link? Look into your running server on shell and click the edit link. See what is the error you are getting.

I could assume that it should be edit.js.erb instead of _edit ...
Also please make sure that you are giving the correct partial location path inside _edit.js.erb

```
render partial: 'form'
```

Comment: nothing happens when I click the edit link, as I mentioned before, I tried to make console.log("whatever") there and it isn't showing it.

Comment: I also checked the development.log file and it doesn't have any error, idk why it isn't showing :/